# How to write a SQL script to get desired output

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Table

```
Member| Mum_Status
mem1  | active
mem2  | future
mem3  | active
mem3  | future
```

How to write a query to get below output from above table

- Future records only needs to populate when member is not currently active
- If member have both active and future status then future record should not be populate

Desired output:

```
Member| Status
mem1  | active
mem2  | future
mem3  | active
```

Answer (score 5):

Do a `GROUP BY`. Use `MIN` to pick active (if available), otherwise future is returned.

```
select member, min(status)
from tablename
group by member
```

Will work very well as long as no other status types are introduced.

Alternatively, `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select member, status
from tablename t1
where status = 'active'
   or NOT EXISTS (select * from tablename t2
                  where t2.member = t1.member
                    and t1.status = 'active')
```

If a row has active status, return it. Otherwise it has future status, return it in case that no other row for same member has active status.